# Casting char->Character in ArrayList#remove() - Why?

Tags: java, typecasting-operator

```
import java.util.*;

public class rearrange_palindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String st=sc.nextLine();

        ArrayList<Character> ar = new ArrayList<Character>();

        for (int i=0;i<st.length();i++){
            if (ar.contains(st.charAt(i)))
            ar.remove((Character)st.charAt(i));//why did they use type casting?
            else
            ar.add(st.charAt(i));
        }
        if (st.length()%2==0 && ar.isEmpty()==true || st.length()%2==1 && ar.size()==1)
        System.out.println("Palindrome");
        else
        System.out.println("Not a palindrome");
    }
}
```

please tell, me the reason why did they use type casting, I've commented that line.

Comment: Who is "they"? Where does this code come from? Are you sure it's not just a mistake by whoever wrote that code?

Comment: `ArrayList` has two different `remove` methods: (i) `remove(int)` and (ii) `remove(Object)` - the first use the argument as index of the element to be removed, while the second removes the given Object - since `charAt()` returns a `char`, both method can be called (a `char` is also an integral type), the compiler will call the first one - casting to `Character` forces the second one to be called

Comment: btw, you've stumbled upon some non-obvious code (good on you for noticing that!). The given answers (and @user16320675's slightly more in-depth explanation) are correct, but if I were you, I would do a favor to the next person who runs across this and add a short comment in the code; something like `// casting to Character so Java uses the remove(T) overload instead of remove(int)`

Answer (score 5):

Removing both chars and ints can lead to logic errors when using the `remove(T e)` because of the overloaded method
`remove(int index)` of the ArrayList class. Casting to their wrapper class avoids this.

Answer (score -1):

The ArrayList class uses generics to specify that it contains a instances of Character. The casting allows automatic boxing char into a Character instance. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/autoboxing-unboxing-java/
The reason behind this, being that unlike in C#, generics are supported for classes but not intrinsic types such as int, char...